# Saving Form Data with an Array in Session Storage

Tags: javascript, arrays, session, storage

I am a new to JavaScript. One challenge I want to solve is that i will save data from a form to the session storage. For that I choose an eventlister, so every click on an add-button pushes the input data to an array.
But in Session Storge nothing will be stored. Sometimes the array has the value null, sometimes no key/value is shown. I try the datatransfer with the two input field. The select options are not involved in my first tests (but they should be also stored). Thats my code:

```js
const input = document.querySelectorAll('.formData')
const btnSubmit = document.querySelector('.pushData')

let inputData

if(sessionStorage.getItem('formdata'))
{
    inputData = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem('formdata'))
} else {
    inputData = []
}

input.forEach(btnSubmit => {
    btnSubmit.addEventListener('click', () => {
        inputData.push(input.value)
        sessionStorage.setItem('formdata', JSON.stringify(inputData))
    })
})
```

```html
<label for="message-text" class="col-form-label">Aufgabe:</label>
<input class="form-control formData" name="task" type="text" required>
                  
<label for="recipient-name" class="col-form-label">Ticket-ID:</label>
<input class="form-control formData" name="ticketid" type="number" required>
                
<label for="message-text" class="col-form-label">Wochentag:</label>
<select id="day" class="formData" name="day">
    <option value="1">Montag</option>
    <option value="2">Dienstag</option>
    <option value="3">Mittwoch</option>
    <option value="4">Donnerstag</option>
    <option value="5">Freitag</option>
</select>
```

It would be very friedly if someone of you can help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are accessing 'value' incorrectly.

Your variable "input" is a nodeList array of 3 length.
correct way ->

```
input[0].value
input[1].value
input[2].value
```

Comment: Thanks for your advice @Anshul. I think it was a beginners mistake. I store the data with this code: `inputData.push(input[i].value)`

Answer (score 0):

You have your button event listener wrapped in the for each, which will try to attach a new event listener each time thru. You might could reverse it and put your forEach inside of the event listener:

---

```
 btnSubmit.addEventListener('click', () => {
            input.forEach(addItem);
        })
    
    function addItem(item) {
     inputData.push(item.value)
    }
    sessionStorage.setItem('formdata', JSON.stringify(inputData))
```